# Change div order on foundation/bootstrap part of row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I have a design where I have 3 divs.

On desktop mode - 2 divs are in the same row, and on mobile mode each of them is a full row, but the order needs to change.

For example this is my HTML (using foundation CSS):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="mobile-first small-12 large-8 columns">FIRST</div>
  <div class="mobile-last small-12 large-4 columns">LAST</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="mobile-middle large-12 small-12">MIDDLE</div>
</div>
```

What needs to happen when I am on mobile screen is that the "LAST" div will go last, even though it is part of the first row.

Is it possible without duplicating the HTML, using JS or using strange float that will act strange on some devices?

This is the fiddle I've made:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1u149tht/2/)

Comment: it's possible with javascript, that you'll append `mobile-last` in last row, which will remove it from previous location, but you need to remember it's previous position if you want to move it back (in case you want to work with portrait/landscape)

Comment: Thanks but I'm not looking for JS solution @moped

Comment: I know .. if you knew exact height of each column, you could've used negative margins. btw you can put all 3 columns into one row, it will work just fine (if it helps..)

Comment: Yes it helps! I didn't know that I can use it all in one row... if I can then it is simple, I can use flexbox.

Comment: sure you can :) check the demo in Docs: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html#basics

Comment: You could use the bootstrap class col-xs-push-6 to change the order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per #moped suggest. I can use same row div for all the colums.
The solution is simple if they are all in the same div, I can use display: flex.

```
  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .row {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    .mobile-first{
       order: 1;
    }

    .mobile-last{
       order: 3;
    }

    .mobile-middle{
       order: 2;
    }
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1u149tht/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap `mobile-first` and `mobile-middle` divs into an additional column. Then apply negative `margin-right` to the `mobile-middle` div on the wide screen.

Please check the result:

### 1) Bootstrap

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/ss8zbf6z/

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 500px;
}
[class|="mobile"] {
  height: 100px;
}
.mobile-first  { background-color: blue;  }
.mobile-last   { background-color: red;   }
.mobile-middle { background-color: green; }

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .mobile-middle { 
    margin-right: -33.33333333% !important;
    width: 150% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="mobile-first col-xs-12">FIRST</div>
        <div class="mobile-middle col-xs-12">MIDDLE</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-last col-md-4">LAST</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### 2) Foundation

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/sbzgwf8t/

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 500px;
}
[class|="mobile"] {
  height: 100px;
}
.mobile-first  { background-color: blue;  }
.mobile-last   { background-color: red;   }
.mobile-middle { background-color: green; }

@media screen and (min-width: 64em) {
  .mobile-middle { 
    margin-right: -33.33333% !important;
    width: 150% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.3/foundation.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 large-8 columns">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="mobile-first small-12 columns">FIRST</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="mobile-middle small-12 columns">MIDDLE</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-last small-12 large-4 columns">LAST</div>
  </div>
</div>
```